# Change the shell that functions use

Tags: terminal, bash

In my current terminal setup, I make use of zsh; it's my default shell. I also have an up-to-date version of Bash for other reasons installed from Homebrew.

However, there is also the Bash provided by Apple which is at version `3.2.57`.

I've my own functions setup and a particular one requires a feature starting from Bash 4.0. Even though my default shell is zsh and I aliased `sh`(Apple's bash) command to `bash`(the bash from Homebrew) command, the function I've defined still defaults to using `sh` and hence, my function doesn't/can't function. I've also changed the shebang at the head of the file defining my custom function but no help.

How can I make that function I've defined default to using the bash installed from Homebrew?

Comment: If you create a subshell to run your function, whatever happens in that subshell is contained only in that subshell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn the function into a shell script and define the shell to be used in the first line

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

# the content of your function goes here
```

Then make the shell script executable and put it somewhere into your `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

The other approach will work, but would fail if `/usr/local/bin/bash` does not exist.

If you want to ensure future compatibility, I'd recommend you specify the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line using `/usr/bin/env`, which ensures your environment uses the path to find the first version of the binary (`bash`).

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# the content of your script
```

If you have configured your environment to search `/user/local/bin` first, this will function as you expect.

You can check where `bash` exists in your path with:

```sh
$ which -a bash
```

Which outputs the following on my system:

```sh
/usr/local/bin/bash
/bin/bash
```

Comment: The requirement from the OP was to *specify* a particular shell, not use the current shell du jour.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually quite insightful.